# web scraping by beautiful soup return error?

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

[![HTML tags appears is the CSV file][1]][1]

Comment: there is no error in the result. you get all `span` tags that have that class.

Comment: Can you share your code? We can not understand the problem while looking at the pictures. @ayahahaha

Comment: Not like this, just edit your question and add your code. @ayahahaha

Comment: you can't share your code as image, you should post it as text. @ayahahaha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is updated version of your code.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import os

csv_file = open(os.getcwd()+"\data.csv", "a", newline="")
csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
csv_writer.writerow(["job_title", "company_name", "location", "job_skills", "link"])

for i in range(0, 10):
    result=requests.get(f'https://wuzzuf.net/search/jobs/?a=hbp&q=python&start={i}')
    soup=BeautifulSoup(result.content,'lxml') 

    base_url = "https://wuzzuf.net"

    # find all job posts card
    job_posts = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "css-1gatmva e1v1l3u10"})

    for job_post in job_posts: 
        job_title = job_post.find("h2", {"class": "css-m604qf"}).find("a").text
        company_name = job_post.find("div", {"class" : "css-d7j1kk"}).find("a").text[:-2]
        location = job_post.find("div", {"class" : "css-d7j1kk"}).find("span").text
        job_skills = job_post.find("div", {"class" : "css-1lh32fc"}).find_next_sibling("div").text

        link = job_post.find("h2", {"class": "css-m604qf"}).find("a")["href"]
        link_full = base_url + link

        csv_writer.writerow([job_title,company_name,location,job_skills,link_full])

csv_file.close()
```

Comment: when I'm trying to scrap multiple pages the output is Just for page number one but duplicated many times, what is the problem  `page=0
for i in range (0,10):
    page=page+i
    result='https://wuzzuf.net/search/jobs/?q=python&a=hbp=0'
    result=result+str(page)
    print(result)  `

Comment: I have updated the code for pagination. @ayahahaha